# Joomla! extensions table is not unique

Tags: mysql

The Joomla! extensions table is not editable in PHPMyAdmin.  I believe there are non-unique values there too, so it cannot have an index.  This is wreaking havoc with my install, I can't add any new extensions etc.

Is there an easy way to fix this?  I have tried database fix but that didn't work.  When I try to do an update on "install from web" it shows two of them, so I think there are duplicate entries for that (and other things).

Is there some sort of SQL script I could run to fix this?

If I try to make a column a primary key or a unique in PHP MyAdmin I get the error that there is an **invalid default value** for `checked_out_time`.  The default value is **as defined** and `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43589048/2943403  I recall having this datetime error last year with multiple columns in core tables.

Comment: Additional links: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/16372 and this post that references J4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890585/2943403

Comment: Thanks Mick you legend I'll give it a go

Comment: (I would've posted as an answer, but I am not confident that it is a complete solution for your task.)

Comment: I'll let you know. I have seen a solution before but I can't find it! And I think my problem is multitiered.

Comment: When you say it is not editable, what do you mean? Are you getting an error message or SQL Error when you try saving record?

Comment: @irata I mean in PHP my admin just clicking on a cell in the table doesn't make it editabke.

Comment: @Eoin any feedback for us regarding my earlier suggestions to repair your table?

Comment: I haven't had time to try it yet. Probably next week I will try. U fortunately it's for a family member and I need to do my paying work first.

Comment: Thanks Mick, I managed to achieve this by exporting a CSV of the table, updating it in Excel, then reimporting it with unique values.  That hasn't solved the problem, I'I think I have multiple problems and I need to solve them bit by bit, but often that's not the case.